# Issues with meteor app on vagrant share

Tags: mongodb, meteor, nfs, vagrant

I have a vagrant VM (virtualbox) setup with meteor. My host and guest are both Ubuntu. The VM contains a vboxfs share folder setup through the Vagrantfile. The behavior I am noticing is similar to a NFS mount.

I am able to create a meteor project in this shared folder, but when I run the project I get errors pointing to mongodb.

If I follow instructions on
https://github.com/pixelhandler/vagrant-dev-env/blob/master/README.md
my app works just fine.

Upon further investigation it seems that MongoDB does not work on NFS shares, http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/NFS

Has anyone else run in to this issue? and if so, have you figured out a (non-rsync) solution?

I plan to send link of this question to 10gen, perhaps someone from their team can answer it.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure what Mongo's plans are re running on NFS / vboxfs, but you could work around this by running your own MongoDB not in the shared folder (eg, use the ubuntu mongodb package). Use the `MONGO_URL` environment variable to tell meteor where to connect. If you pass this variable, meteor will not try to start MongoDB in the meteor project directory.

Comment: I'll also note that in vagrant you shouldnt specify the PWD or HOME env vars as it will also cause error.

Answer (score 4):

You can move the  data dir somewhere inside the VM, and use a symlink from the vagrant folder:

```
cd /vagrant/.meteor/local
ln -s ~/db/
```

This means the data will not be shared, but you probably want it git ignored anyway.

(https://grahamrhay.wordpress.com/2013/06/18/running-meteor-in-a-vagrant-virtualbox/)

Comment: Is just the MonoDB data stored in .meteor/local? I've seen other solutions what mount the entire .meteor folder, but that screws up meteorite.

Comment: If `/vagrant` is an NTFS, `ln -s` says `ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘./homedb’: Protocol error` though it might be possible with a [`mklink`](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/) to an FS that `ln` understands.

Answer (score 0):

grahamrhay's solution would not work with the vagrant box started on Windows. There is no way to make symbolic links on windows for vagrant, at least not for administrator accounts.