# Run Meteor.js as a root

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, root, meteor

The reason I want to run Meteor.js as a root is just I need to correctly execute Meteor's mongod process in directory owned by root.

I have ubuntu server VM in VirtualBox which have a shared folder with host.
My Meteor.js app locates in this folder. Owner of the files in the shared folder is root.

When I run meteor by user or by root (sudo) mongod process claims an error. Error comes from wrong execution permissions.

There is why I need to execute Meteor.js as a root.

> ***sudo meteor*** doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but by your description you may be suffering from the problem Mongo has with NFS shared folders. [See this question for details and workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676868/issues-with-meteor-app-on-vagrant-share)